# Bootstrap - WordPress Conversion

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

This is not exactly a specific question, I am just looking for some advice really.

I know how to create websites using Bootstrap however I have just realized that WordPress has an awful lot of great plugins (contact page, ecommerce sites, blog plugins) that would come in very handy for the Bootstrap website I am trying to create.

I am wondering is it possible to integrate the 2 platforms together so I can keep my custom bootstrap layout and responsiveness but that I am able to incorporate some of the handy plugins that WordPress provides also.

Thanks
Colm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yes, you can use any plugins with Bootstrap you want because if the plugin is not in the Bootstrap framework then it will have its own class and CSS for desktop and responsive mode so it will not conflict with Bootstrap hierarchy.

You can also overwrite the CSS if you want that will also help.